# </div></div> auto closing create child not sibling

Tags: google-chrome, browser, xml-parsing, custom-tag

I really like to use "short closing" for tags using ordinary `<tag/>` format but unfortunately using such method in Browser (i.e. chrome) cause quite unexpected behavior.

When in document I have:

```
<div/><div/>
```

it's interpreted as

```
<div>
   <div></div>
<div>
```

no matter what DOCTYPE i use (XHTML) or HTML5 I just get this in a wrong way.
I'm also using this "notation" for custom tags in namespace `<widget:aSampleWidgetA/>` `<widget:aSampleWidgetB/>` which also introduce this problem.

I don't want to use a full closing notation as its making a lot of visual mess in code.
Is there some way to force Browser to parse those tags as proper XML?

Comment: While it may be more code to specifically include the closing div tags, I think it may be clearer to other developers who may work on the code as it is the convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to make browsers (except of IE8 and below) parse the markup as XML. You need to serve it with the proper XHTML content type `application/xhtml+xml`.

Doctype is irrelevant for parsing, it affects only rendering mode (Standards or Quirks). When served as `text/html`, all pages will be parsed by HTML rules (HTML5 rules for modern browsers), which effectively mean that end slash in the 'self-closing' syntax is just ignored, and the ability of the element to be 'self-closed' is actually hard-coded in the parser. `Div`s and custom tags don't have this ability.

Answer (score 6):

Apologies, I can't find great documentation on this but I suspect it is because a `div` is not a valid self closing tag. Looking at the [XHTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html), empty tags are specifically marked as *EMPTY*, `div` is not, so Chrome instead behaves as if it is html5 where the closing tags are can be left off and takes a best guess as to where to close them.

Alternatively, if you don't like the look of html, perhaps you might prefer something like [haml](http://haml.info) or [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) templates.

Comment: To extend this point, it may be possible via document rewriting in JS or via nonstandard schema, but as <divs> are not marked as singletons, you can't.
A third option is not to use standard HTML.  An XML document and a CSS include to display it, should work in most cases.